# Grouping Ids with respect to dates

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Hi I have a Scenario ,

```
ID          Actual Date Expected Date   Tenure Date
ABC900P01   4/21/2020    4/21/2020       7/10/2020
ABC900P02   6/12/2020    6/12/2020       9/10/2020
ABC900P03   9/15/2020    7/18/2020       1/14/2021
ABC900P04   11/20/2020   10/9/2020       2/14/2021
ABC900P05   12/15/2020   12/15/2020      3/21/2021
ABC900P06   1/20/2021    1/20/2021       5/16/2021
```

I want when Actual date and expected date are equal then min of Actual date and min of Exoected date and max of Tenure date . Else if they are not equal keep it as it is .

Expected result:

```
ID         Actual Date  Expected Date   Tenure Date
ABC900P01   4/21/2020   4/21/2020        9/10/2020
ABC900P03   9/15/2020   7/18/2020        1/14/2021
ABC900P04   11/20/2020  10/9/2020        2/14/2021
ABC900P05   12/15/2020  12/15/2020       5/16/2021
```

Comment: Why aren't ABC900P02 and ABC900P06 returned?

Comment: Hi, This is beacuse when Actual date and expected date are same then i am taking the min of ID , actual and Expected date and Max of Tenure date ,                           next when the dates are not equal i want to keep it as it is . Then it continue again with the same process